# Regarding the use of Asynchronous shared memory (ASHMEM) in android apps written in java

Tags: android, memory-management, ipc, shared-memory, ashmem

How android applications (not native apps) which are actually in dalvik byte code can be benefited from ASHMEM. Are their any API in android framework for application developers?

I know this is kind of a generic question but I would not have put it here unless I have already tried and did not get a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read about MemoryFile, see this doc page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html

Comment: Great! I was looking for something like this.